# Integrable functions have zero limit at infinity at least in one subsequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let assume that $f$ is a function in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
I know that if also $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $f$ has zero limit at infinity. Or more generally if $f$ be a uniformly continuous function then 
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0. $$

Now my question is this: 
If merely $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, is this true that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $ a_n \to \infty$ and
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n)=0. $$

Comment: You probably want to assume $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \infty$.

Comment: @Arthur: yes, i corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(1)**
For a Lebesgue integrable function $f(x)$, there always is such a sequence.  If there is no such subsequence, then it means 
$$
\liminf_{x\to+\infty}\; |f(x)| \ne 0 .
$$
Thus there is $A>0$ and $a>0$ so that $|f(x)|>a$ for all $x > A$.  So
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|\;dx \ge \int_A^\infty a\;dx = +\infty
$$
And therefore $f \not\in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

**(2)**
For Riemann improper integral, we can use the [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity)
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{i x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}}\;(1+i)
$$
which converges, but the integrand has modulus $1$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is true. Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is nonnegative. Suppose such a sequence did not exist. Then, there should exist a $t>0$ and an $M>0$ such that $f(x)>t$ for all $x>M$. But this implies the integral of $f$ blows up, since $f$ is now larger than $t>0$ on $[M, \infty]$.