# Integrability of a function and its derivative and propositions about the limits at zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

I have been scouring this site and have been confused by the responses. Please see ([Integrable functions have zero limit at infinity at least in one subsequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512315/integrable-functions-have-zero-limit-at-infinity-at-least-in-one-subsequence)) and ([Integrable absolutely continuous $f$ with integrable $f'$ has limit $0$ at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472757/integrable-absolutely-continuous-f-with-integrable-f-has-limit-0-at-infin))

To clear this up, which of the following statements are true, which are false and why?

1) $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f' \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=0$.

2) $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f' \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Finally, do these hold for $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ as well? Do you know of any book that will contain these proofs (should they be correct statements)?

EDIT: 3rd point removed due to it being trivial.

Comment: When you say things like $f'\in L^1$ it is vague. Do you mean $f'(x)$ exists everywhere?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of 2): Let $\epsilon>0.$ Because $f'\in L^1,$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$$m(E)<\delta \implies \int_E|f'|\,dm <\epsilon.$$

Now suppose $|y-x|<\delta.$ WLOG, $x<y.$ Then

$$|f(y)-f(x)| = |\int_x^y f'| \le \int_x^y |f'|<\epsilon.$$

Therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Proof of 1): Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ fails. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_1<x_2<\cdots\to \infty$ such that $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon$ for all $n.$ Passing to a subsequence, we can assume $x_{n+1}-x_n>1$ for all $n.$

From 2), we know $f$ is uniformly continuous. Thus there exists $0<\delta <1$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ implies $|f(y)-f(x)| <\epsilon/2.$ Consider the pairwise disjoint intervals $I_n=[x_n, x_n+\delta], n=1,2,\dots.$ Argue that $x\in I_n$ implies $|f(x)|>\epsilon/2.$ Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb R} |f| \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I_n}|f| \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\epsilon/2)\delta = \infty,$$

a contradiction. Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ as desired.

Comment: I can follow all of your answer apart from "Argue that $x \in I_n$ implies $|f(x)|>\epsilon /2$". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: $|a-b|\ge |a|-|b|.$ Take $a= f(x_n), b=f(x_n)-f(x).$

Comment: That’s excellent, thank you. One last question before I accept your answer, does similar reasoning hold for $x\longrightarrow -\infty$?

Comment: Sure. In fact all we need is to apply the above to $f(-x).$

Comment: Do you know of a book or paper which contains this or a similar question and proof?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that might appear in a text as an exercise. Unlikely to find it in a paper.